# Text is shifting to the far left/right after adding new lines to a PDF in Acrobat X

Tags: pdf, textbox, adobe, newline, acrobat

When I add a new line to text in Acrobat X (standard) it shifts all text in the same text box below the new line to the left or right. For each new line added it shifts farther to whichever side it is heading until it is off the page completely. I can backspace the new lines and everything goes back to where it was originally. Any idea why this is happening or how it can be fixed?

Comment: Unless you wrote Acrobat X, this has nothing to do with programming. Better asked on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) (general application-related advice) or [Graphics StackExchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might also ask in the Acrobat community (answers.acrobatusers.com) to reach the PDF/Acrobat experts.